# How to get name of any class?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to make an extension function for logging. I want to send `Any` as a parameter and get its name. But can not find how to get name of `Any` class. Have any idea about it?

```
fun MainActivity.log(claz: Objects,any: Any){
    Log.d("Main", claz.name +  any.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val c = String::class
println(c.simpleName)

$ String
```

- [Class References](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html)
- [KClass](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html)

Comment: Be aware that using ::class will result in the actual class being instantiated. In some cases that can have a bad side effect.

Comment: @AndroidDev if you have side effects in constructors you have bigger problems to worry about then getting the name of it.

Comment: @AndroidDev it won't instantiate the actual class. Check hashCode, it always stays the same. You have to either call () or TYPE::class.java.newInstance() to instantiate a new instance.

Answer (score 3):

Use `yourClassInstance::class.simpleName`:

```
fun MainActivity.log(claz: Objects, any: Any){
    Log.d("Main", "${claz::class.simpleName} ${any::class.simpleName}")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Class or KClass for that, but using a KClass is best for this case. Otherwise you'd have to add `.java` to the class, as Blue Jones mentioned.

I'm not sure *which* name you want. Remember, there can be multiple JVM classes with the same name. A `Closeable` for an instance could be either [java.io.Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), or a custom implementation if you're also using a library that uses one for whatever practical reason it might have.

Considering that, there are valid usecases where you'd want the qualified name. The qualified name is identical to the "regular" name, except it also includes the package. Consider this for an instance:

```
import java.io.Closeable;

fun main(ar: Array<String>){
    val closeable = Closeable::class
    println(closeable.simpleName)
    println(closeable.qualifiedName)
}
```

This would print:

```
Closeable
java.io.Closeable
```

You'll have to pick which one you want to use, which depends on your use. If you want the package too, use `qualifiedName`. Otherwise use `simpleName`.

You obviously don't have to get the class by doing `ClassName::class`. You can also do the same on instances, which means you can do `any::class` and use that to grab the name.

So in order to get the name, use `any::class.qualifiedName`. If you just want the class name excluding the package, use `simpleName`.

It is worth noting that KClass is [a part of the reflection package](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/). I therefore assume it uses reflection in a few or all the calls.

What this means is that you can get a SecurityException if the permissions are denied. I tested most of this on [try.kotlinlang.org](https://try.kotlinlang.org/), and I got a SecurityException with lambda in the main method when using `KClass#qualifiedName` and `KClass#simpleName`.

Using `::class.java` fixed that. So if you're experiencing security exceptions, use `class.java`. The naming is virtually identical. `simpleName` is there, but `qualifiedName` is simply `name`. Which one you pick is up to you, but either works.

So your code would look like either of these:

```
println(any::class.qualifiedName) // Alternatively with simpleName
println(any::class.java.name) // Alternatively with simpleName
```

And finally, I see you called `toString()` on one of the instances. This returns the qualified class name with a hash after it. That is also an option, but if you don't want the hash, use Class or KClass.

Also, I see you used `MainActivity.log` as your function. I really don't see why. If you have a logging function that's limited to a single class, put it in the companion object. Declaring extension functions inside the class itself is also pointless, because the calls are identical. Since you can edit the class, and it's a single class we're talking about, you can move it to the companion object (optionally, make it private).

And your code could benefit from using string templates, which I'll add in the final example. This is to make sure the spaces end up right. With your current code, there's no space added. I can't find `Objects#getName()` either, so I assume it's another attempt at getting the name itself. ***However:*** The `Objects` class, assuming it's `java.util.Objects` cannot be initialized. It's a utility class. If you meant `java.lang.Object`, use `Any` instead. Any is roughly the same as Object.

Which means your class could look like this:

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    ...
    companion object {
        fun log(claz: Object, any: Any){
            Log.d("Main", "${claz::class.java.name} ${any::class.qualifiedName}") // I'm mixing the calls here to show you that you can use either. You can of course pick which you use.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed something alike for objectmapping raw json response as objects and managed to make it work like this

```
val depositResponse = convertResponseToObject(response , DepositResponse ::class.java.name) as DepositResponse
val withdrawResponse = convertResponseToObject(response , WithdrawResponse ::class.java.name) as WithdrawResponse
fun convertResponseToObject(response: String?, type: String ): Any{
    try {
        when (type) {
            DepositResponse ::class.java.name -> 
                 return ObjectMapper().readValue(response, DepositResponse ::class.java)
            WithdrawResponse ::class.java.name -> 
                 return ObjectMapper().readValue(response, WithdrawResponse ::class.java)
            else -> throw Exception("Error Mapping the json response")
        }
    }catch(e:Exception){
        throw e
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
println(any::class.simpleName)
println(any::class.qualifiedName)
println(any::class.name)

println(any::class.javaObjectType.name)
println(any::class.javaObjectType.canonicalName)
println(any::class.javaObjectType.simpleName)
println(any::class.javaObjectType.typeName)

println(any.javaClass.simpleName)
println(any.javaClass.canonicalName)
println(any.javaClass.typeName)
println(any.javaClass.name)

println(any::class.java.simpleName)
println(any::class.java.typeName)
println(any::class.java.name)
println(any::class.java.canonicalName)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.